# AngularJS directive template class not rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-templates

I have a simple directive which returns a template. The issue is that the class used in the template isn't working. Here is the HTML code:

```
 <div ng-app="mapp">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
        <div class="panel">
            <check-list></check-list>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the directive:

```
.directive('checkList',function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        template: function(elem,attrs){
            return '<div class="inner">Hello</div>'
        }
    };
});
```

And here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zo9wk8gd/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS rule doesn't work because `.inner` div is not a direct child of the `.panel`, since Angular inserts template into `check-list` element.

You have two options.

The first is to use `replace: true` configuration of the directive:

```
.directive('checkList',function() {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        template: function(elem, attrs) {
            return '<div class="inner">Hello</div>';
        }
    };
});
```

**Demo 1:** http://jsfiddle.net/zo9wk8gd/2/

And the second is to change CSS rule to be

```
.panel .inner {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

**Demo 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/zo9wk8gd/4/

Comment: Seems like `replace` is deprecated: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: @Cherniv Yes, it will be removed in Angular v2.0. But I wouldn't worry about this, since there will be no easy migration from v1.x to v2.0 anyway. And not because of `replace` :)

Answer (score 1):

**CSS solution:**

you have style

```
.panel > .inner{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

which defined a background-color blue to the direct child `.inner` of `.panel`, but what structure you have is:

```
<div class="panel">
        <check-list><div class="inner">Hello</div></check-list>
    </div>
```

So `.inner` is not direct child of `.panel`

---

Change your style to this:  http://jsfiddle.net/zo9wk8gd/1/

```
.panel  .inner{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

or this http://jsfiddle.net/zo9wk8gd/5/

```
 check-list >.inner{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

---

If you want to dig into correct way of creating a replace template , see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28604957/3556874) from dfsq

Answer (score 0):

your directive outputs like below

```
    <check-list><div class="inner">Hello</div></check-list>
```

So you are getting final output like below.

```
<div class="panel">
    <check-list><div class="inner">Hello</div></check-list>
</div>
```

so the selector `.panel > .inner` would failed to apply css rules.

to take the effect just change directive like this:

```
.directive('checkList',function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        template: function(elem,attrs){
            return '<div class="panel"><div class="inner">Hello</div></div>'
        }
    };
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3hu18xge/1/) is working fiddle